# OpenGL 3.2 : cast right shadows by transparent textures

Tags: opengl, glsl

I can't seem to find any information on the Web about fixing shadow casting by objects, which textures have alpha != 1.

Is there any way to implement something like "per-fragment depth test", not a "per-vertex", so I could just discard appearing of the fragment on a shadowmap if colored texel has transparency? Also, in theory, it could make shadow mapping be more accurate.

**EDIT**

Well, maybe that was a terrible idea I gave above, but only I want is to tell shaders that if texel have alpha<1, there's no need to shadow things behind that texel. I guess depth texture require only vertex information, thats why every tutorial about shadow mapping has minimized vertex and empty fragment shader and nothing happens when trying do something with fragment shader.

Anyway, what is the main idea of fixing shadow casting by partly-transparent objects?

**EDIT2**

I've modified my shaders and now It discards every fragment, if at least one has transparency o_O. So those objects now don't cast any shadows (but opaque do)... Please, have a look at the shaders:

```
// Vertex Shader
uniform mat4 orthoView;

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec2 in_TextureCoord;
out vec2 TC;

void main(void) {
TC = in_TextureCoord;
        gl_Position = orthoView * in_Position; 
}
```

.

```
//Fragment Shader
uniform sampler2D texture;

in vec2 TC;

void main(void) {
vec4 texel = texture2D(texture, TC);
if (texel.a < 0.4)
    discard;
}
```

And it's strange because I use the same trick with the same textures in my other shaders and it works... any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean? Depth *is* tested per-fragment. If you want to avoid *writing* to the shadow-map per-pixel, that's quite possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use discard in the fragment shader, then no depth information will be recorded for that fragment. So in your fragment shader, simply add a test to see whether the texture is transparent, and if so discard that fragment.